# Django: how to include the file?

Tags: python, django-urls

I have a Django Application.
I want to have all my models to be separated in files and lay in the specific directory, for instance:

```
/usr/project/models/myModel.py
```

Is it any possible?
Just importing through from myModel import * doesn't work, unfortunately.

Is there any specific way to do this?

Comment: Can you say more about how it doesn't work?

Comment: sure, it says that the particular file doesn't exist(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create file `/usr/project/models/__init__.py` containing `from myModel import *`. `__init__.py` file is required to make directory a python package.

Answer (score 0):

You can split your models into separate files, it's just Python code.

Comment: @opetrov: the standard import statement rules apply.  Simply read up on the import statement.

Comment: @s.lott from myModel import * does not work since there's no such package named myModel.